# print the text box value in list view in windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

here I attach a code to get the value in text block, but I want to print the txt1 and date1 value in list view

### xaml code

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" x:Name="myList">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txt1"  Text="{Binding date1}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="txt2"   Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

### c# code

```
textBlockNumber.Text = "1232"  
txt1.Text = textBlockNumber.Text;
```

DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;

Comment: Can you please show us the code of your list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to add a item source of the list box  ..

```
List<data> asd = new List<data>);
asd.Add(new data(textBlockNumber.Text,DateTime.Now));
myList.ItemSource = asd;
```

make a data class

```
public class data
{
   public string liststing {get;set;}
   public DateTime datetime {get;set;}

   public data(string textblocktext,DateTime date)
   {
     this.liststring = textblocktext;
     this.datetime = date;
   }
}
```

then bind the text of textblock in xaml like `Text="{Binding liststring}"` and your other  `Text="{Binding datetime}"`

i hope it helps ...